# Cómo convertir Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017 a formato epoch?

Tags: java, android

```
public String DateFormatoEpoch()  {
    String epoch="";
    Date fecha = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
    String fechaString = fecha.toString();


    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");

    long epochLong = 0;
    try {
        epochLong = df.parse(fechaString).getTime();
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"epochLong "+ epochLong);
epoch = epochLong+"";

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"epochDateError "+ e.getMessage());
    }return epoch;
}
```

El resultado me da un **Error**:

> W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Nov 27 
>       20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017" (at offset 0)

Comment: Espero mi respuesta te ayude.

Comment: No es posible que el código tal como lo tienes te de ese error. El código ni siquiera compila porque le asignas un `String` a un `Date`.

Comment: El código en realidad es correcto, @JoelRomero  el problema es el formato que no es el adecuado de acuerdo a el string con la fecha que defines, debe ser "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo, solucioné con sus respuestas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La definición de tu fecha de acuerdo a el formato que defines: "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017", no debe ser como objeto:

```
Date fecha = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
```

Debe ser como String

```
String fecha = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
```

Además el formato que defines es incorrecto:

```
"MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"
```

debe ser:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

Te recomiendo revisar [Patrones de Fecha y Tiempo en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

De acuerdo a lo anterior y de acuerdo a la definición:

> El tiempo **Epoch** es la hora actual medida en número de segundos
>   desde el Epoch Unix.

esta es la forma de obtener tu fecha en `Epoch`:

```
    Long epochLong = null;
    String strDate = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
    try {
        epochLong = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(strDate).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

Este sería el método de acuerdo a tu código para obtener `Epoch` de acuerdo a tu formato de fecha definido:

```
public String DateFormatoEpoch()  {

    String epoch="";
    String fechaString = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    long epochLong = 0;

    try {
        epochLong = df.parse(fechaString).getTime();
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"epochLong "+ epochLong);
        epoch = String.valueOf(epochLong);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"epochDateError "+ e.getMessage());
    }

    return epoch;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su colaboración, me funcionó perfectamente al cambiarle a EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy, También obtuve la fecha actual con un método que convertí Date a String así:  String fechaString = df.format(fecha);

Comment: Excelente @JoelRomero un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

El primer error que tienes es que estás asignando un `String` directamente a un Objeto `Date`?

```
Date fecha = "Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
```

El segundo error es que el formato de fecha que usas es incorrecto, este formato "MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz" no es igual a la Fecha que introduces.

Te pongo el código corregido :

```
public String DateFormatoEpoch()  {
        String epoch="";
        String fechaString ="Mon Nov 27 20:10:20 GMT-05:00 2017";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        long epochLong = 0;
        try {
            epochLong = df.parse(fechaString).getTime();
            epoch = epochLong+"";
            System.out.println(df.parse(fechaString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }return epoch;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó.